# weighted QQ Plot in R

Tags: r, graphics, distribution

I am using the `car` package in R for a QQ plot with an underlying exponential distribution. I am handing the `qqplot()` function the vector `t` (with the values) and specify `distribution=exp`.
However, is there any way (as possible in SAS) or also in the density function (for sure this is different from qq Plot) to weight the values in the QQ Plot with a vector of weights? Or is there any other way to generate a QQ plot with an exponential expectation and a weighted curve?

Thanks

Comment: `qqplot` does not support weights, but you may want to read this thread on R-help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101675.html

Comment: I was wondering..is it just odd to weight in a qqplot? Or is is valid but just not commonly done?

Comment: I have not seen it commonly, but I am not an expert so I would not comment on the validity... (maybe a question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `wtd.quantile` function in package Hmisc. Or the quantreg package functions will accept a weights argument if you need increased generality. I don't remember that the qqplot uses quantiles directly but I may be wrong about that. (Furthermore, `qqplot` is in pkg:stats, not in car.)

Comment: My understanding is that qqnorm computes the quantile of each value then maps those valueto a standard normal distribution.  For a weighed distribution you would need to calculate the weighted quantile of each observation then use those values to map to the normal distribution. As such the to use wtd.quantile from Hmisc is a good one